# Better Media Key controls?

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard

I'd like a better way to control iTunes, Rdio and other audio applications on my computer with my media keys. Ideally, this app would allow me to say that the default media keys will always operate one app and specify modifier keys for other applications (Such as <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>▶</kbd> to play/pause Rdio).

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) allows me to control these apps with text strings, but I'm specifically looking for a way to use my media keys for quick pauses or skips.

Currently, the media keys will control whatever media player you last focused. This means that you may be attempting to pause a song in Rdio, but a recent iTunes App Store search means that you start playing two songs instead.

Comment: please let me know if you find a solution to this, as it might help in my similar issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283395/get-media-keys-to-always-play-latest-media-run