# get media keys to always play latest media run

Tags: itunes, keyboard, google-chrome, mediaplayer

I don't use spotify, but I do use apps from what I'm guessing are 3 different categories that handle media keys in different ways:

- chrome
- apple apps (itunes, quicktime, etc)
- everything else (mplayerx, vlc, etc)

I bet spotify, rdio etc would get into one of those categories.

if [chrome global keys](http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/) are activated with the media keys (by any extension or google music app), everything works as expected, except for apple apps.

if I disable (or uninstall) chrome global keys, then the rest gets back to the normal expected behavior from the title, including [opening itunes](https://superuser.com/questions/31925/what-can-i-do-to-stop-the-play-pause-button-from-opening-itunes).

from all this I deduce there should be a way to get media keys to simply play the last thing that was played. always.

unfortunately no idea how to achieve this. [magic keys](http://www.gearmusicplayer.com/extras.html) won't resolve it. no amount of patch or solution from all the links here helped so far, while a [similar question went unanswered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94507/better-media-key-controls) for years.

perhaps this question would be better for stackoverflow since, in practice, I'm already working to resolve this by abandoning itunes and quicktime. :P